# PHP while loop times

Tags: php, timeslots

This is my first time try to use object oriented programming. I'm trying to repeat the timeslot from the database but I'm only getting one result.

timeslot table contains:

```
10:00:00  
10:15:00
10:30:00
```

in PHP class:

```
 class booking {
     function __construct($mysqli) { 

     }

     function get_timeslot() {
         global $mysqli;

         $q = $mysqli->query("SELECT id_timeslot, times FROM timeslot");

         while($r = $q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) :
             return $r['times'];
         endwhile;

         $mysqli->close();
     }
 }
```

in the webpage to showing the looping times:

```
 $booking = new booking($mysqli);

 <?php echo $booking->get_timeslot(); ?>
```

result:

```
10:00:00
```

Comment: You cannot simply return something more than once in PHP. There is some archaic code to accomplish things like that. But you don't need to here. Create a new array of $r['times'] and return that array. Then do a foreach on that new array outside your method. Or echo them in the method, not return them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

return is returning the value for your function, thus you'll only receive 1 value returned.  Try

```
echo $r['times'].'<br/>';
```

or

```
 function get_timeslot(){
     global $mysqli;

     $q = $mysqli->query("SELECT id_timeslot, times FROM timeslot");
     $timeSlots = array();

     while($r = $q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
     {
         $timeSlots[] = $r['times'];
     }

     $mysqli->close(); 
     return $timeSlots;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

the return statement stops the while loop from continuing any further, and exits the function. You'll either need to modify the function to return an array of time slots, or modify your logic to expect only the first result from the database.

Answer (score 1):

The `return` statement will exit the function immediately it's called. Instead return you should add the item to array than return the entire array:

```
class booking {

 function __construct($mysqli){}

 function get_timeslot(){
  global $mysqli;
  $q = $mysqli->query("SELECT id_timeslot, times FROM timeslot");

      while($r = $q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) :
       $res[] = $r['times'];
      endwhile;
  $mysqli->close();
  return $res; 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 function get_timeslot() {
     global $mysqli;

     $q = $mysqli->query("SELECT id_timeslot, times FROM timeslot");

     while($r = $q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) :
         // Cast to array
         $t[] = $r['times'];
     endwhile;

     $mysqli->close();
     // Return Array
     return $t;
 }


 // Calling the function
 $booking = new booking($mysqli);
 // Add print_r() as the return is now in an array format
 echo "<pre>".print_r($booking->get_timeslot(),true)."</pre><br />\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using return $r['times']; inside the loop.

This should solve your problem:

```
function get_timeslot(){
  global $mysqli;
  $returnArray = array();
  $q = $mysqli->query("SELECT id_timeslot, times FROM timeslot");
  while($r = $q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) :
       $returnArray[] = $r['times'];
  endwhile;
  $mysqli->close(); 
  return $returnArray; // now that all results are fetched from DB, return array containing them
}
```

On other note, using global keyword inside a class method or anywhere for that matter i not advisable, since global scope enables any process to access and change global variable.
I would advise you to try using other means of accessing your DB object (object registry, protected property...)

Also using alternative syntax for while loop (while(): ... endwhile;) is not very readable, but one can debate about that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class booking {
function __construct($mysqli){}
function get_timeslot()
{
    global $mysqli;
    $q = $mysqli->query("SELECT id_timeslot, times FROM timeslot");
    $return = '';
    while ($r = $q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) :
        $return.= $r['times'] . '<br/>';
    endwhile;
    $mysqli->close();
    return $return;
}}
```